# Formatted Input in Table in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, user-input, sqlplus

I want to input the following things -

```
ACCEPT p_cname PROMPT 'Enter Customer Name: '
ACCEPT p_cyear PROMPT 'Enter Car Year: '
ACCEPT p_color PROMPT 'Enter Car Color: '
ACCEPT p_make PROMPT 'Enter Car Make: '
ACCEPT p_model PROMPT 'Enter Car Model: '
ACCEPT p_trim PROMPT 'Enter Car Trim: '
ACCEPT p_enginetype PROMPT 'Enter Car Engine Type: '
ACCEPT p_option PROMPT 'Enter Option Name: '
ACCEPT p_ocode PROMPT 'Enter Option Code: '
```

then add it in table as

```
NAME -  WANT

Name - year color model trim enginetype 'w/' Option ( ocode )
```

I tried to format it using -

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES ('&p_cname', '&p_cyear' || ' ' || '&p_color' || ' ' || '&p_make' || ' ' || '&p_model' ||
        || ' ' || '&p_trim' || ' ' || '&p_enginetype' || ' ' || '&p_option' || '(' || '&p_ocode'      || ')');
```

BUT IT DOED NOT WORK.

Comment: And what exactly does "does not work" mean?  (There is no need to use all caps, by the way.)  Are you getting an error message?  Is the data appearing wrong?

Comment: /Enter Customer Name: SQL> Enter Car Color: SQL> Enter Car Model: SQL> Enter Car Engine Type: SQL> Enter Option Code: SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8  
Enter value for p_cyear: asf
old   4: VALUES ('&p_cname', '&p_cyear' || ' ' || '&p_color' || ' ' || '&p_make' || ' ' || '&p_model' ||
new   4: VALUES ('ACCEPT p_cyear PROMPT 'Enter Car Year: '', 'asf' || ' ' || 'ACCEPT p_make PROMPT 'Enter Car Make: '' || ' ' || '' || ' ' || 'ACCEPT p_trim PROMPT 'Enter Car Trim: '' ||

Comment: Enter value for p_trim: asdf
Enter value for p_option: adfg
old   5:         || ' ' || '&p_trim' || ' ' || '&p_enginetype' || ' ' || '&p_option' || '(' || '&p_ocode' || ')');
new   5:         || ' ' || 'asdf' || ' ' || 'ACCEPT p_option PROMPT 'Enter Option Name: '' || ' ' || 'adfg' || '(' || '' || ')');

Comment: VALUES ('ACCEPT p_cyear PROMPT 'Enter Car Year: '', 'asf' || ' ' || 'ACCEPT p_make PROMPT 'Enter Car Make: '' || ' ' || '' || ' ' || 'ACCEPT p_trim PROMPT 'Enter Car Trim: '' ||
                                *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 33:
PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Sorry the error was too long so I had to divide it into parts.

Comment: You should edit the question to put the information in the question.  After doing so, you can also delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The error you pasted into comments doesn't correspond to the code in your question. If I execute the code I get:

```
SQL> @test
Enter Customer Name: a
Enter Car Year: b
Enter Car Color: c
Enter Car Make: d
Enter Car Model: e
Enter Car Trim: f
Enter Car Engine Type: g
Enter Option Name: h
Enter Option Code: i
old   2: VALUES ('&p_cname', '&p_cyear' || ' ' || '&p_color' || ' ' || '&p_make' || ' ' || '&p_model' ||
new   2: VALUES ('a', 'b' || ' ' || 'c' || ' ' || 'd' || ' ' || 'e' ||
old   3:     || ' ' || '&p_trim' || ' ' || '&p_enginetype' || ' ' || '&p_option' || '(' || '&p_ocode'      || ')')
new   3:     || ' ' || 'f' || ' ' || 'g' || ' ' || 'h' || '(' || 'i'      || ')')
        || ' ' || 'f' || ' ' || 'g' || ' ' || 'h' || '(' || 'i'      || ')')
        *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression

SQL>
```

That's because you have two [concatenation operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators003.htm) missing it's second operand:

```
'&p_model' || || ' ' || '&p_trim'
```

Eliminate the extra operator and the `insert` works:

```
'&p_model' || ' ' || '&p_trim'
```